# Are there factors which caused the printing revolution to begin in Europe in 1450 and not some other place some other time?

Tags: europe, 15th-century, printing

The printing press was a big deal. It brought a communication revolution and led to the development of larger collective consciousnesses.

What I am refering to the *printing revolution*  is the widespread dissemination of written content by publishing, widespread creation of content to be printed and widespread consumption of printed material.

Gutenberg was a *spark* which lit the fire of the printing revolution. But how widespread or rare was the....*fuel* and the *oxygen*?

Two parts

- Could it have been occurred as readily in any year before 1450?
- Could it have been occurred as readily in any sedentary civilization other than Europe?

I understand that it is broad, and borders opinion based, but, indulge me?

Comment: A relatively simple writing system was no doubt a huge factor for industrialising printing.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press#Economic_conditions_and_intellectual_climate) on the topic. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 9):

A modern misconception was that Gutenberg invented printing; this was not the case. [Woodblock printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_printing#Woodblock_printing_(200_AD)) was a craft over a thousand years old when he came about.

Another misconception was that Gutenberg invented moveable type; this was not the case either. [Moveable type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_printing#Movable_type_(1041)) was invented four hundred years before Gutenberg's time in China, and made its way to Europe eventually.

What Gutenberg *did* invent were various tools and procedures to print *more*, *faster*, and *cheaper* (most importantly the [hand mould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_mould) and the [printing press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press), which significantly sped up the process). This allowed European printing to *catch up* with Chinese/Korean book production, and *eventually* overtake it.

So it is more appropriate to look at Gutenberg's work as a big *evolutionary* step, not actually a *revolution*. He didn't invent all of it in a blaze of divine inspiration; he (significantly) optimized existing processes.

---

There were corroborating factors that helped the "taking off" part in Europe.

One of them was already brought up by @Semaphore -- alphabets (prevalent in Europe) are easier to set in print than [syllabaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabary) or [logograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logogram), as there are fewer glyphs to chose from. This is a gradual quality, though; it is certainly possible to use moveable type with e.g. the Chinese writing system (see above).

Another factor favoring Europe was the high demand by wealthy patrons for one specific, large book -- the bible -- offering high potential profits that could be re-invested.

So... yes, it *could* have happened earlier, or in a different place of the world. It *did* happen in other places, to be exact -- it just did not "take off" the way it did in Europe.

Comment: Also the religious conflicts starting around the 1520's accelerated the usage of printing presses in England and Germany.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Printing had certainly had its part in propaganda elsewhere as well; I don't see that as a distinguishing factor making Europe special. I like to err on the side of caution when it comes to Euro-centrism.

Comment: Such events often establish a product for long term usage. The point where it becomes a common everyday item that then spreads.

Comment: The first part of your response does not answer my question much. I had already known and considered it while writing the question. Can you expand more in the second part?

Comment: @Rohit: I am not sure what there is to expand on. As you mentioned yourself, the question is broad and opinion-based, bordering on alternative history. There were factors that made printing easier and more profitable in Europe than in China (where the basic technology originated), and with Gutenberg's improvements, it got *much* easier and even *more* profitable...

Comment: Mark Johnson, I'm curious as to why that had that effect - perhaps printing of pamphlets to gain support for or against the "other" church?